# Execute 100 times a command with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have this bash code:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in /path/*.html
do
 python3 main.py  $f &
done
```

the `/path/*.html` contains over 6000 file, now what I want to do is to execute simultaneously the Python function on first 100 files and when it's done it goes and run the other 100 and so on.

Comment: Are you asking how to write the bash script or how to write the Python code in `main.py`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to implement that in Python? Have a look at [mutiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: @mkrieger1 i want to work with bash code, but this code runs all the files, while i want only the first 100 to be runned and so on.

Comment: So the question is not actually related to Python.

Comment: @mkrieger1 am open to a python solution, just i need the 100 files to be executed simultaneously

Comment: `xargs` has an option `-P`, which allows commands to be run in parallel. This is perhaps less work than creating the child processes manually. Another possibility would be to use [gnu-parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: i did try @Shawn answer but it didn't work for me!!

Comment: @user1934428 I think your contribution would be a good answer.

Comment: @hagello this answer worked very well for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67928999/16085212, but i had to add nohup command before python command : nohup python3 main.py &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly put the multi-processing inside `python` using threading, multi-processing or with a wrapper like `dask`.

If you want the command line repetition, I highly recommend [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for running one command with lots of files/arguments.  `parallel` is generally considered a [more modern and powerful replacement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104778/gnu-parallel-vs-i-mean-background-vs-xargs-p) for `xargs`.

```
parallel --eta python3 main.py {} ::: /path/*.html
```

To get it to act on 100 files at once, use the `-n` parameter:

```
parallel -n 100 --eta python3 main.py {} ::: /path/*.html
```

If you have too many arguments, then use find to generate the list and pass it in via `stdin`:

```
find /path -name \*.html | parallel -n 100 --eta python3 main.py {}
```

Comment: but it doesn't run a 100 times first then go for the next 100

Comment: do you need the output to be ordered?  `parallel` by default will run as much as possible in parallel but won't assure ordering of the output text unless you specify `-k`.

Comment: no i don't need things to be ordered just runned in parallel, when i tried your code i got tis error: -bash: /usr/bin/parallel: Argument list too long

Comment: normally main.py has an output with i don't see it, it should be enabled or what please, bc when i hit top i can see processes but no outpout

Comment: you can drop the `--eta` which is just to help you guess how long it will run.  Instead, redirect everything to a file `parallel .... > output.log` or something.

Comment: thanks!!!!! finally it did work, i had to go down to 70 file so the CPU can make the treatments

Comment: `parallel` tries to use a number of cores on your processor depending on what's available.  If you need less cores used because of memory constraints (for example), you can use the `-j` flag to specify the number of simultaneous jobs you want at once.

Comment: actually it did run only the first 100 files succesfully, then it stops not runs the next 100 files and so on: last working code: find /path  -name \*.html | parallel -n 70 -j 70 --eta python3 main.py {}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a GNU userland:

```sh
find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0 -P100 -n1 python3 main.py
```

will launch 100 instances of the python script (And start new ones when they exit, until all the files have been processed).

Comment: it's not working, when i do lunch it the server just freeze, idk if the problem is from the command or my server!!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you don't want to keep exactly 100 processes running at a time (or as close as possible), you can just keep a counter to let you know when to wait for the existing processes to complete:

```
i=0
for f in /path/*.html; do
    python3 main.py "$f" &
    i=$((i + 1))
    if [ "$i" -eq 100 ]; then
        wait
        i=0
    fi
done
wait  # In case the loop exits before i==100
```

Comment: i think i must be given a value before line 3 !!

Comment: It probably should be, but the first time it gets used is inside `$((...))`, where it defaults to 0 if it isn't already set.

Comment: I do want to keep exactly 100 processes running at a time, and when the 100 processes are over it goes to the next 100 processes and so on till the path/*.html is over

Comment: Surprinzinly adding nohup command on python, and everything started working, thanks a lot

Comment: @user16085212 Otherwise? What happens if you don't add it? Is there something special about your `main.py`?  Do you have to add nohup even if you parallelize, say, `sleep 10`? The word _surprisingly_ leaves me curious.

Comment: @hagello according to what i did inderstand is that without using nohup some processes get killed in the background and the process finishe faster than expected, so what i wanted to do is to add a log file to see what's going on on the background, that's why i added nohup command into python command in sh script, and all of sudden everything worked prefectly, but after 2 hours of use, i got disconnected from server, so i did use nohup command over my sh script: nohup sh run_all.sh and everything worked prefectly, i didn't try the parallel command with nohup, but i think it should work